# .Net Core 5 Create Order and OrderDetail

Tags: asp.net-core, repository

I am creating Order including OrderDetail. When I have a Cart consisting of many Products, I create an Order, I want each product ID to be added to the OrderDetail including the OrderID.

But currently, I only get a ProductID (OrderID) in the first loop added to the OrderDetail. When I debug, the loop still executes enough times quantity of Product in Cart but is not added to OrderDetail.

So what is the problem that I am facing here?

**Repository**

```
public bool CreateOrder(CartViewModel invoiceVM, string userId)
    {
        invoiceVM.Invoices.CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
        _dbContext.Invoice.Add(invoiceVM.Invoices);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        decimal orderTotal = 0;
        var cartItems = GetCartItem(userId);
        foreach (var item in cartItems)
        {
            var invoiceDetail = new InvoiceDetails
            {
                ProductId = item.Products.Id,
                InvoiceId = invoiceVM.Invoices.Id,
                Price = item.Products.Price * item.Quantity,
                Quantity = item.Quantity,
            };
            orderTotal += (item.Quantity * item.Products.Price);
            _dbContext.InvoiceDetails.Add(invoiceDetail);
        }
        invoiceVM.Invoices.OrderTotal = orderTotal;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"but is not added to OrderDetail" You mean that the Order is created in your database, But you can't see any OrderDetail in your database ?
if

```
_dbContext.InvoiceDetails.Add(invoiceDetail);
.
.
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

are successfully pass with no errors, It save data in your database and I think it's your CartViewModel that is not updating.
you can add your data to CartViewModel in you loop or run another GetInvoice() from your dbContext.

Comment: If I have multiple Products in my cart, it only saves in InvoiceDetail 1 single product with InvoiceID. And the remaining Products will disappear.

Comment: When I try to remove


`invoiceVM.Invoices.CreateAt = DateTime.Now;
        _dbContext.Invoice.Add(invoiceVM.Invoices);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Remove here`

All Products will be saved to InvoiceDetail but InvoiceID =0

Comment: Is `invoiceVM.Invoices.Id`  0?  If so,can you share your code which pass CartViewModel invoiceVM to `CreateOrder'?

Comment: @YiyiYou Sorry for this delay. My computer is broken and I am in quarantine because of Covid-19 so it is difficult to fix it [https://paste.mod.gg/wahajafimi.csharp] . Here is my code